# Removing every 2nd and 5th column in a matrix in r

Tags: r

I am working on a problem set where i'm being asked to remove every 2nd and every 5th column from a very large matrix mA

```
mA = matrix(rnorm(10000), nrow = 100, ncol = 100)
```

I can easily figure out how to do one of either, but i'm having a hard time figuring out how to do both at the same time. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mA[,!(seq(ncol(mA)) %% 2 == 0 | seq(ncol(mA)) %% 5 == 0)]`

Answer (score 2):

Using vector recycling you can do -

```
result <- mA[, c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)]
```

Comment: This doesn't remove the 4th column (every 2nd column was to be removed).

Comment: A modification does seems to work (it had to be this long for some reason, simply sitting number 4 to FALSE doesn't work):

Comment: mB = mA[, c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)]

Answer (score 0):

We can also do

```
result <- mA[, -unique(unlist(lapply(c(2, 5), function(i) seq(1, ncol(mA), by = i))))]
```